# Transform an image to a bitmap

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, scikit-image

I'm trying to create like a bitmap for an image of a letter but I'm not having the desired result. It's been a few days that I started working with images. I tried to read the image, create a numpy array of it and save the content in a file. I wrote the code bellow:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize

image = io.imread(image_path, as_grey=True)
image = resize(image, (28, 28), mode='nearest')
array = np.array(image)
np.savetxt("file.txt", array, fmt="%d")
```

I'm trying to use images like in this link bellow:

[Letter "e"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4zOy.jpg)

I was trying to create an array of 0's and 1's. Where the 0's represent the white pixels and the 1's represent the black pixels. Then when I save the result in a file I can see the letter format.

Can anyone guide me on how to get this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this one out:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('road.jpg')
ary = np.array(img)

# Split the three channels
r,g,b = np.split(ary,3,axis=2)
r=r.reshape(-1)
g=r.reshape(-1)
b=r.reshape(-1)

# Standard RGB to grayscale 
bitmap = list(map(lambda x: 0.299*x[0]+0.587*x[1]+0.114*x[2], 
zip(r,g,b)))
bitmap = np.array(bitmap).reshape([ary.shape[0], ary.shape[1]])
bitmap = np.dot((bitmap > 128).astype(float),255)
im = Image.fromarray(bitmap.astype(np.uint8))
im.save('road.bmp')
```

The program takes an rgb image and converts it in a numpy array. It then splits it in 3 vectors, one for each channel. I uses the color vectors to create a gray vector. After that it comperes elements with 128, if lower than writes 0(black) else is 255. Next step is reshape and save.

[image: road.jpg]
[image: road.bmp]

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you. What if I needed to resize all my bitmaps to 32x32? How could I do it?

Comment: I would like to resize image to 32x32 or other resolution, without deforming it too much and lose its format. I would like a default resolution so I could create a dataset of these images.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Sorry, I don't have this answer. I myself am using tensorflow and I have little experience with opencv. I don't know if it's worth it for you but I would suggest that you choose a library that covers your needs, stick to it and if you encounter problems ask in stackoverflow. Have fun :)

Comment: Just one more question. I tried to use the same code for the image https://imgur.com/nSz1Lxd and it didn't work. I get an error about axis.

Comment: The image is a two dimmensional array (128, 128), means one channel (not RGB). You can get the shape of the array with `print(ary.shape)`. This is also not a bitmap image; I checked it with `print([elem for elem in range(1,255) if elem in ary]). I updated my answer with some documentation. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just ignored the R,G,B split and rewrote like this: https://imgur.com/PyTsZWf. I resized the image and in the end I saved the result in a txt file that has the format of the letter. So if I have an image that I want to create a bitmap I just need to verify if it's a RGB image first? And could you tell me what are the numbers used to multiply on lambda?

Comment: I don't know. It's just a function from internet. Please ask another question in stackoverflow. Comment are not to be used as a chat. Stackoverflow has chat rooms also.

Comment: The `list(map(lambda x: 0.299*x[0]+0.587*x[1]+0.114*x[2], zip(r,g,b)))` can be done much faster in numpy. It is simply `0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b`. Otherwise, a very nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

**You can use pillow**

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("haha.jpg")
img = img.tobitmap()
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes three steps to do it. First convert original image to a list of pixels. Second change every pixel to either black(0,0,0) or white(255,255,255). Third convert the list back to image and save it.

code:

```
from PIL import Image

threshold = 10

# convert image to a list of pixels
img = Image.open('letter.jpg')
pixels = list(img.getdata())

# convert data list to contain only black or white
newPixels = []
for pixel in pixels:
    # if looks like black, convert to black
    if pixel[0] <= threshold:
        newPixel = (0, 0, 0)
    # if looks like white, convert to white
    else:
        newPixel = (255, 255, 255)
    newPixels.append(newPixel)

# create a image and put data into it
newImg = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
newImg.putdata(newPixels)
newImg.save('new-letter.jpg')
```

`threshold` is what decides a pixel being black or white, as you can see it the code. Threshold of 50 looks like this [image], threshold of 30 looks like this [image], threshold of 10 looks like this [image], if you tune it down to 5, the output starts to lose pixels: [image].

Answer (score -1):

Using PIL

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open("sample1.png").save("sample1.bmp")
```